# SharePoint Designer doesn't show anything in "List and Libraries" link

Tags: listview, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have an issue regarding viewing "List and Libraries" in SharePoint Designer 2010. Earlier it was working but now whenever I click on it, it shows that "There are not items to display in this view". But I am able to see all the lists and libraries in "All Files". I have checked all my list and libraries and able to browse them.

Can anyone guide me what next I can try?

Thanks

Comment: It seems I found the issue. It's related to a library which is already deleted by I can see it while browsing the site. I am not able to see that in SharePoint Designer. I tried deleting using stsadm -o forcedeletelist but with no luck. Anyone has any idea about the same how to delete a already deleted site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found the issue. It's related to a library which is already deleted by I can be seen it while browsing the site. I am not able to see that in SharePoint Designer. You have to go to the DB directly and find out the list GUID from All_Lists table using the name and delete it from there. This solved my problem. I know touching DB is not recommended but you have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint Designer -> All Files -> Lists -> Select deleted list -> Right click -> Delete